# Java (IntelliJ Idea) - import class fail

Tags: java, jsp, intellij-idea

I have a jsp page that imports a class from another module and package.

```
<%@ page language="java" import="login.UserLogin" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=windows-1251" %>

<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Page title
    </title>
</head>
<body>

<%-- Form to initiate POST --%>
<FORM name="test_form" method="post">
    <INPUT type="submit" name="submit" value="Make Post"><BR>
</FORM>


</body>
</html>
```

I've corrected oll the dependances in IDE, but still get an error log:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp
```

The imported class is empty, so there are no further dependances.

Comment: This seems like a deployment error to me, it seems like the appserver can't load your compiled JSP page for some reason. How are you running the app?

Comment: Mada a Tomcat configuration in IDE... The thing is that it runs JSP pages normally if they don't have imports.

Comment: Make sure the sources reside in a source folder that is compiled to the output folder and that compiler output is included into your web artifact.

Comment: @CrazyCoder You should never need to precompile JSPs these days.

Comment: @millimoose It has nothing to do with precompilation, rather the availability of the required classes in the server classpath.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Ah, I misunderstood, having checked the OP's self-answer I get it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found! Error in Tomcat deployment config - it referenced to source folder instead of artifact

Comment: Check Project Structure -> Artifacts - I've already forgot where I made the setup ((( soz.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSP's are internally compiled to a servlets called [your_jsp]_jsp.java and your IDE is saying that it cannot find that compiled class.

Your problem is that your project is not compiled / not deployed in the server. Or maybe you have not well configured the output directory... I don't know, I don't use intelliJ...